# symfony2 - Twig: Configure parent template from child?

Tags: layout, symfony, twig

I'm new to sf2/twig and I think I'm missing a point somewhere:

I have a layout with a header, two-column middle part and footer. The middle part has the main content area on the left, and a 33% sidebar on the right. I use twig's template inheritance to put my content into the main area and where otherwise required.

Now, there are some sections of our page where the content area must take up the whole width, so the sidebar on the right isn't displayed for these sections. To achieve this, I have to apply a different CSS class to the main content area and, obviously, don't render the sidebar's content.

It would be cool if I could use a variable in the main template like `{% if single_column_layout %}`, with a default value of `false`, which I could overwrite in the child template when needed. But it feels like I'm heading in the wrong direction with this...

In a more general way, on a page made of a bunch of building blocks, how would one best control which blocks are displayed and which are not, per page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use twig block inheritance for that:

```
{# layout.html.twig #}
<div id="main" class="{% block column_layout 'single-column' %}">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

Then in your other template, if you want to change the class of your div#main, just reimplement the block

```
{% extends "layout.html.twig" %}
{% block column_layout 'two-column' %}
{% block content %}
     content here
{% endblock %}
```

PD: `{% block name content %}` is a [shortcut syntax](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html#block-shortcuts) for blocks with little content

Comment: Yes, that's an option. The only downside to that solution is that I would have to do both: overwrite the side block _and_ set the CSS class in each child template where I want to have a single column layout, but I guess it's the best option I have, so I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think is impossible to do that. But you can maybe use a twig block with a default value for do that.

I explain. In the main twig, you put this :

```
{% block parent %}
With your value to display by default
{% endblock %}
```

And in the child, if you don't want to display the content, you do that :

```
{% block parent %}{% endblock %}
```

But I'm not sure this way solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, that's the usual twig inheritance, and this would make me get rid of the sidebar content, but that wouldn't help me changing the CSS class of the main content area.

Comment: as netmikey says to you, you could leave "blank" the section you're not intereste in, into your child template. If you want to change the class "dynamically" i suggest you to assign your class directly into the block (main) that you're extending into child template. In that way, you can simply extend your parent, where it's good. Otherwise you can overwrite it and change the class.